# Splitting a column of a Pandas dataframe using multiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have this column in Pandas:

df['GPS'][0]:
0       '39.21,38.6;39.23,38.68;39.26,38.68'

I would like to split the column into:

```
Xcoord1 Ycoord1 Xcoord2,Ycoord2, Xcoord3, Ycoord3
37.21    38.6    37.23   38.68    37.26    38.68
```

My approach is to first split the column using:

df['GPS_list']=df['GPS'].apply(lambda x: x.split(';'))

df['GPS_list']:

['39.21,38.6','39.23,38.68','39.26,38.68']

Now I would need to split based on , to separate the x and y value which I am not sure how to do for each row. Can I use apply function work here?

Next, I would need to convert each of those values from string to int.

Is there an elegant way to do this in a step or two?

I am new to Python and Pandas so any nudge in the right direction is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It If you always have the same number of coordinates, a simple [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) will work:

```
out = (df['GPS'].str.split('[,;]', expand=True)
       .set_axis(['Xcoord1', 'Ycoord1',  'Xcoord2', 'Ycoord2', 'Xcoord3', 'Ycoord3'], axis=1)
      )
```

If you have an arbitrary number of pairs, you can use:

```
out = (df['GPS'].str.split(';', expand=True).stack()
       .str.split(',', expand=True)
       .set_axis(['Xcoord', 'Ycoord'], axis=1).unstack()
       .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
      )

out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{x[1]+1}')
```

Output:

```
  Xcoord1 Ycoord1 Xcoord2 Ycoord2 Xcoord3 Ycoord3
0   39.21    38.6   39.23   38.68   39.26   38.68
```

Comment: Thank you! There are over 60,000 rows so this is taking a while to run. I will mark the answer as the right one as soon as the code is done running.

Comment: The code continues to run (for over 20 mins now) and my memory is maxed out (64 gbs) for a dataset of 55,000 and over 50 coordinates in a row but it worked as expected on a smaller dataset of 3 coordinates and 1000 records.

Comment: @new_to_code sorry to hear that. How many coordinates do you have per row? 60k * 6 is not that crazy, I'm surprised this takes that much memory.

Comment: in the final dataset, each row has around 25  xy coordinate pair. total of 60,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['39.21,38.6;39.23,38.68;39.26,38.68'], columns=['GPS'])
```

`df`

```
    GPS
0   39.21,38.6;39.23,38.68;39.26,38.68
```

---

**Code**

```
col1 = ['Xcoord1', 'Ycoord1', 'Xcoord2', 'Ycoord2', 'Xcoord3', 'Ycoord3']
df['GPS'].str.split(r'[,;]', expand=True).set_axis(col1, axis=1)
```

`result`:

```
    Xcoord1 Ycoord1 Xcoord2 Ycoord2 Xcoord3 Ycoord3
0   39.21   38.6    39.23   38.68   39.26   38.68
```

Comment: Thank you! the code continues to run (for over 20 mins now) and my memory is maxed out (64 gbs) for a dataset of 55,000 and over 50 coordinates in a row but it worked as expected on a smaller dataset of 3 coordinates and 1000 records.